# F# zip implementation

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive

I can't figure out how to implement the Zip function in F#.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Here is what I have typed into `fsi.exe`:

```
> let rec zip xs ys =
-  match xs with
-   | [] -> []
-   | head :: tail -> (match ys with
-                       | [] -> []
-                       | headY :: tailY -> (head, headY) :: zip tail tailY);;

val zip : xs:'a list -> ys:'b list -> ('a * 'b) list

> zip [1;2;3;4] ["a","b","c","d"];;
val it : (int * (string * string * string * string)) list =
  [(1, ("a", "b", "c", "d"))]
```

Comment: Alternative: 
let rec zip2 xs ys = 
    match xs,ys with
    |xh::xt,yh::yt -> (xh,yh)::(zip2 xt yt)
    |_,_ -> []

https://dotnetfiddle.net/9TkL3k

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example `["a","b","c","d"]` is a list that contains one element which is 4-dimensional tuple. That is why you are getting unexpected results from zip.
Just use `;` as elements delimiter instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth pointing out that it's probably worth making the `zip` function tail-recursive as well in order to avoid stack overflows on larger lists.

Something like this perhaps

```
let zip3 xs ys = 
  let rec loop r xs ys =
    match xs,ys with 
    | [],[]         -> r
    | xh::xt,yh::yt -> loop ((xh,yh)::r) xt yt
    | _ -> failwith "xs & ys has different length"
  loop [] xs ys |> List.rev
```